# ManyToMany self-referenced with extra column in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have problem which is easy to solve with pure SQL but I need to solve it with Doctrine in YAML.

I have well known db tables users and friends. Where users table has primary key `user_id` and friends has `friend_id` and `friend_with_id` which uses user_id from table user. My problem starts when I need to add there one more column mood. With SQL I add to table friends onemore column named mood and it's done with doctrine I can't find any solution.

For better understanding I add db scheme:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any self-reference relationship here. Both friend_id and friend_with_id points to users.user_id. What I see is, two one-to-many relationships from the user side OR two many-to-one relationships from the friends side.

So, there will be two ArrayCollection objects (ManyToOne) in the Friend entity corresponding to friend_id and friends_with_id. Similarly two ArrayCollections (OneToMany) on the User entity, namely, myFriends and friendsWith.